# CV using tabular environment

Tags: tables, cv, tabulary

I would like to write my CV in LaTeX but I am not able to replicate the example in the picture. I tried using the tabulate environment but I don't understand very well how it works.

Do you have any suggestion on where to start?

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you maybe show the code of what you tried so far and maybe ask more specifically what troubles you?

Comment: What troubles me is that I do not know where to start from. What I tried so far is less than a working minimum, I've only managed to recreate the upper part of the CV (name, address, telephone, email).

Comment: There are many packages available especially for CVs. You may use them. You will find them here https://ctan.org/topic/cv?lang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use any of the CV templates (see e.g. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv)), maybe to be more flexible, you can use the following code as a start.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \cventry{time range}{what}{optional explanation}
\newcommand\cventry[3]{%
  \par\medskip\noindent% separator between cv entries
  \parbox[t]{3cm}{\bfseries#1}%
  \hspace*{1em}% column separator
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-1em}% text width - width left col - width separator  
    {\bfseries#2}%
    \def\tmp{#3}%
    \ifx\tmp\empty\else
      \\#3%
    \fi
  \end{minipage}%
}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\Large
  {\bfseries Name Surname}\\
  {\normalsize Address}\\
  {\normalsize +XX XXX XXXXXXX}\\
  {\small email@mail.com}
\end{center}

\section*{Education}
\cventry{XXX--present}{xxxx University -- Country}{Bachelor in XXX}
\cventry{XXXX--XXXX}{xxxx High School -- Country}{%
  High school diploma in XXX\\
  Final mark: XX/100
}
\section*{Work Experience}
\cventry{Jul XXXX}{xxxx -- Country}{%
  Job Title
}
\cventry{Oct--Dec XXXX\\{\small(Weekends only)}}{xxxx -- Country}{Job Title}
\end{document}
```

[image]